# MIPS , printing stored data from array

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to print the 2 values of data1 with a loop , but im not able to locate the adress of the 2 elements properly and i get an out of bounds error .

When I run the code , the output is `(null)(null)`.

```
.data



DATA:    .word data1,data2,data3

data1:   .word nome1,cognome1
name1:       .asciiz "john"
surname1:    .asciiz "cena"


data2:    .word nome2,cognome2
name2:       .asciiz "giorno"
surname2:    .asciiz "giovana"


data3:   .word nome3,cognome3
name3:       .asciiz "nikola"
surname3:    .asciiz "tesla"



.text

main:

addi $s0, $zero, 0
li $t5,1              ##counter

while:

la $s1,DATA
la $s2,0($s1)


do:

li $s3,3            ##if s3 = 3 end
beq $s3,$t5,exit

lw $t1,0($s2)       ## print elements in data1
la $a0,0($t2)
li $v0,4
syscall

addi $t5,$t5,1

increaseS1:       ##increase s1 so you can print next data

addi $s2, $s2, 4 

j do

exit:

li $v0,10 # exit
syscall
```

How can I locate the adress properly without making the code too huge ?, the idea of this programa is to print all the `DATA` elements one by one by looping and aumenting the indexs.

Comment: `la $a0,0($t2)` <-- Why `$t2`? It doesn't look like you assign anything to that register anywhere in your program.

Comment: im no really sure , but I think is for the memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data1:   .word nome1,cognome1` <- shouldn't that be `data1:   .word name1,surname1`?

So in *DATA* you have three pointers on the *dataN* data, and *dataN* consist of two pointers to the ascii zero terminated strings.

But the code looks like you only load the pointer to the *dataN* data (`lw $t1,0($s2)`), not loading the pointers for strings itself. You have to use that $t1 to load first pointer to name, call the syscall to display it, and then again to load second pointer to surname and display it. Maybe something like `lw $t2,0($t1)` for name, and `lw $t2,2($t1)` for surname.

edit: next paragraph of my answer is wrong, now I see what you did there ($t5 being counter, and it's used probably correctly, except not using it for DATA access.. and that would need counting from 0, not from 1).

*But it looks like you are using random registers all around without loading them by values, like `li $s3,3`, looks like $s3 was supposed to be index over `DATA`, but you don't init it to zero, and you don't use it in `lw $t1,0($s2)` to fetch *dataN* pointer either.*

If you do have some interactive debugger, try your code and see how the registers are filled/used, I think you are copy/pasting the code from different pieces (each using it's own registers), so they will not work together.

**You** have to decide what to put into which register, and then stick to it in the rest of the code.

Comment: Oh god , I didnt see those errors, happens that I have to write this program in Italian but when I need help I have to traduce it to english lol

Comment: If it works, it works by some accident I think, because there are still those problems (uninitialized $t2 usage as Michael pointed out, and you load only pointer from DATA, not string pointers from data1/2/3). I think you are at the point where stepping in debugger line by line, and trying to understand what's happening, will give you biggest advantage + you will be able to fix it all on your own easily.

Comment: hmm... and I didn't pay enough attention to your original source, so my answer has lot of mistakes too... argh. So follow just the ideas, not actual numbers/instructions. ;) Sorry, I'm not used to mips asm.